# How to fix a bathtub faucet that leaks only when the shower runs?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, bathtub

I just moved into an apartment and the faucet in the tub is fine when all of the water is off. It leaks when I turn on the water and switch it to the shower head. What could be the problem?
It's a rental so I don't want to take the switching mechanism off to investigate. I suspect it's some sort of rubber seal in the switch.

**UPDATE**

The control is a twist knob between the cold and hot twist knobs.

Comment: What kind of diverter valve do you have?  Is it set in the wall or a pull knob on your tub spout?

Comment: A picture might help (unless you have the model number, that would help more).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the washers/gaskets on the valve have gone bad, you'll have to either replace the washer or the entire valve (if you can find a replacement).

Here is what the valve may have looked like when it was new (*just to give you an idea of what you're dealing with*).

[image]

## Removal

- Turn off the water to the shower faucet using either a local shutoff valve or the main water valve for the house.
- Turn the shower’s hot and cold water all the way on, to drain leftover water from the pipes.
- Pry the cap out of the center of the diverter’s handle.
- Remove the screw in the middle of the handle, and then pull the handle off the faucet.
- Unscrew the metal sleeve that sits over the valve stem.
- Insert a [Shower Valve Socket Wrench](http://www.sears.com/misc-shower-valve-socket-wrench/p-SPM685856401P) over the valve stem and turn the dirervter anti-clockwise to remove it.

[image]

- Replace the washer, *or the whole diverter if you can find a replacement*.
- Apply some [Silicone grease (*plumbers grease*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone_grease) to the washer before replacing the diverter.

[image]

## Installation

Installation is the reverse of removal.

- Insert a Shower Valve Socket Wrench over the valve stem and turn the dirervter clockwise to install it.
- Screw on the metal sleeve that sits over the valve stem.
- Push the handle on the faucet, then replace the screw in the middle of the handle.
- Push the cap into of the center of the diverter’s handle.
- Turn the shower’s hot and cold water all the way off.
- Turn on the water to the shower faucet using either a local shutoff valve or the main water valve for the house.

Comment: Thanks @shirlockhomes.  I spent enough time on the site, it's about time I finally learned something and was able to give a good answer ;)  I think in this situation though, the true answer is "call the land lord to fix it".